# .Net Core web api needs to consume web service from configuration file

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .Net Core application I am consuming Web Service using 
Add -> Connected services -> WCF Service Preview(nuget package) and added the web service and used the service methods.

However, now clients moved the Web Service to internal Web Servers and I do not have access to the service from my development environment. So I am not able to access the service methods and build my solution and publish.

Is there any way I can pass the Service URL from Configuration file?
Example:
For Dev Environment - http://dev.svc
For Prod Environment - http://prod.svc

Comment: `Is there any way that I can give the Web Service URL from Configuration file as I do not have access to the service from my development environment`. What are you asking?

Comment: Is there any way I can pass the Service URL from Configuration file ? Example : For Dev Environment - http://dev.svc 
For Prod Environment - http://prod.svc

Comment: You can use Config transforms for different values per environments https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply @ColinM
I am using .Net Core and I guess it will be different in it

Comment: Do I need to change anything in Reference.cs ?

Comment: On .NET Core you should have an `AppSettings.json` file, and several transforms for `AppSettings.Production.json`

Comment: Here's a link describing the NET Core version https://blog.elmah.io/config-transformations-in-aspnetcore/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I suggest you to read whole article about the configuration in `ASP.NET Core`, as there are lots of things you may find useful. In general, you can get the config files for each of environments with code like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

            // note that here we do override the values by specific file for an emvironment
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)

            // and this line will get the environment variables from server machine
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

`JSON` files could be something like this:

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "serviceUrl": "",
}
```

`appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "serviceUrl": "http://dev.svc",
}
```

`appsettings.Production.json`

```
{
  "serviceUrl": "http://prod.svc",
}
```

Also you may find useful the [Working with multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) article.